# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-adapter

I am trying to retrieve time of my post from Firebase timestamp to the Feed activity through an Adapter and Viewholder. But, when I launch my app, it crashes.
what could be the possible reason for that. Except that everything is working fine, I mean, Image Url and EditText data are retrieving safely. How to retrieve Time and display it in my feed. In the below code, the error is thrown at first line.

```
long millisecond = feed_list.get(position).getTimestamp().getTime();
String dateString = DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy", new Date(millisecond)).toString();                       
holder.setTime(dateString);
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the exception

Comment: feed_list.get(position).getTimestamp() = null emplies timestamp should be initialized before being invoked.

Comment: feed_list.get(position).getTimestamp() is null, check it

Comment: @Michael I posted stacktrace

Comment: How to initialize it. I am quite new to programming. please tell me @MohammadTabbara

Comment: How to make it Not Null.. @OussemaAroua

Comment: can you show were you initialize feed_list, but if you are getting it null from a server then M_I said the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize your `timestamp` behind `getTimestamp()` or avoid the `NullPointerException` by checking the condition if it needs to be empty.

```
if (feed_list.get(position).getTimestamp() != null) {
    // do something
}
```

`NullPointerException` is thrown if you try to access a method - in your case `getTime()` on class `Date` which is `null`.